# One time created Web Api token is working on all request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-web-api, token

I want to ask Web Api token based authentication. As a user, I am creating a token on a web api. Token link is `http://mydomain/token` This request is returning a long token string. I am using this token to get secured data like this:

`http://mydomain/orders
 Accept:application/json
 Content-type:application/json
 Authorization: Bearer lksKaBgTgNT06LAWzHeLHiwMUI6nBHNvE2qen9............`

This header info is working with ajax request on Chrome browser. But same token is working with another browser Firefox or IE.

Is this a security risk? If someone knows my token who listen network can access my data. Should I prevent this stuation with https?

Comment: Yes this is a security risk - You should definitely be securing this with an SSL connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is working the way it should. To the server it doesn't matter from which browser it came from, as long as the token is valid it will process the request and send back the response.

To solve the problem, you can use any (or all) of the following strategies:

1. Encrypt the request and response (https).
2. Have small token lifetime (say 30 minute) and re-issue token using a refresh token.
3. Use a client id along with the token. Issue token specific to a client id.